# 'str' object does not support item assignment when inserting to pymongo collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

RHEL 6.5, python 2.6.6

I'm trying to write decoded messages in to a MongoDB collection.  The "decoded message" is received in the form of a dictionary.  Within that dictionary the keys are all strings, and the values can be strings, integers, `datetime.time`, `datetime.datetime`, or `Decimal` types.

I've written an `on_message` function which is called with a parameter `context` contining the dictionary to be saved to MongoDB.  I've also written a lambda to convert some types that aren't JSON serializeable.

```
dthandler = lambda obj: (
    str(obj) 
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal)
    or isinstance(obj, datetime.time)
    else None
)

class Decoder(decoder.base.Base):

  # ...

  def on_message(self, context, payload):

    """  Write decoded message to DB
    """
    msg = dict(context)
    try:

        print self.mongo_coll

        # This is just a test to confirm the connection is established properly.
        # I am able to see this value in the DB using Robomongo after this insert 
        # call
        self.mongo_coll.insert({'foo': 'john'})

        x = json.dumps(context, default=dthandler)
        print x
        self.mongo_coll.insert(x)
    except errors.OperationFailure as op:
        print "Operation Exception"

    except Exception as ex:
        print "Serialization Exception (mongo/write.py)"
        exs = str(ex)
        print exs

        print '^^^^^'
```

The call to `print self.mongo_coll` yields:

> Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'itch'),
>   u'test')

the call to `print x` yields (all results are similar):

> {"msg-type-name": "AddOrderAttributed", "next-expect-msg-seq-num":
>   3023982, "mold-num-msgs": 34, "recv-timestamp": null, "ord-ref-num":
>   4365786, "msg-type": "F", "recv-time-nano": 2523000, "raw-price":
>   781200, "msg-seq-num": 3023981, "shares": 100, "buy-sell": "B",
>   "stock": "RNR", "attribution": "RBCM", "timestamp": "09:30:00.002189",
>   "price": "78.12", "tracking-number": 1, "recv-time-sec": 1419431400,
>   "msg-size": 40, "mold-seq-num": 3023959, "stock-locate": 6281,
>   "mold-session": "000006896B", "msg-payload": "00 28 46 18 89 00 01 1f
>   1a ce fb 57 59 00 00 00 00 00 42 9d da 42 00 00 00 64 52 4e 52 20 20
>   20 20 20 00 0b eb 90 52 42"}

However the call to `self.mongo_coll.insert(x)` yields an `Exception`:

> Serialization Exception (mongo/write.py)
>
> 'str' object does not support item assignment
>
> ^^^^^

I'm quite confused especially given that there is no mention of `str` in my code, except in my exception handler and within `dthandler`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Per edits and answers, I've made a couple modifications.  Alas, I'm still having trouble.  Here's the new code:

```
 def on_message(self, context, payload):
    """  Write decoded message to DB
    """
    msg = dict(context)
    try:
        print self.mongo_coll
        self.mongo_coll.insert(msg)
        x = json.dumps(context, default=dthandler)
        print self.mongo_coll
        print x
        self.mongo_coll.insert(msg)
    except errors.OperationFailure as op:
        print "Operation Exception"
    except Exception as ex:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "Serialization Exception (mongo/write.py)"
        exs = str(ex)
        print exs

        print '^^^^^'
```

...and the output:

```
Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'itch'), u'test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./decoder/mongo/write.py", line 69, in on_message
    self.mongo_coll.insert(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 409, in insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.uuid_subtype, client)
InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: Decimal('65.1')
Serialization Exception (mongo/write.py)
Cannot encode object: Decimal('65.1')
^^^^^
```

Comment: in order to debug the error you should use `traceback.print_exc()` this will give you the full traceback instead of just the message (of coarse you need to `import traceback`)

Comment: @JoranBeasley:  Thanks for that pointer.  I'll do that now.

Answer (score 2):

Your line here

```
x = json.dumps(context, default=dthandler)
```

Makes `x` a string. Simply use

```
self.mongo_coll.insert(msg)
```

It's better not to insert `context` directly, rather insert `msg` (which is a `dict`, not a context object).

Comment: Do you mean to say `self.mongo_coll.insert(context)`?

Comment: I see, thanks.  However now pymongo (I think) is complaining that `Cannot encode object: Decimal('65.1')`.  Please see my edited OP for full detail.

Comment: I'd redirect you there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongokit/dQWe9mejy0o

Comment: @JohnDibling it's a well-know issue that has its solutions, but honestly I haven't dug deep into them, so I wouldn't give you some recommendation on this point.

Comment: @JohnDibling instead of editing your OP to add this point, you really should ask a whole new question on its own. Because this one seems solved now (unless there's anything not clear?)

Comment: Something's still not clear.  I went through my codebase and changed all the places where I was inserting a `Decimal` in to the dict and inserted a string instead, so now there are no `Decimals` at all.  Now, when I try to `insert(msg, default=dthandler)`, I still get mongo errors:  `in gen\n    doc[\'_id\'] = ObjectId()\nTypeError: \'str\' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: I'm unclear what this error stems from, since it doesn't appear to be related to `msg`, but to the auto-generated `_id` column.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if this was resolved or not.  But I was having the same issue, so I'll post my solution here to help others.

I'm working off [this example](https://github.com/dwatrous/mongodb-packt/blob/master/section-2-json-data-operations/video-2.2-schema-and-structure/python-example.py).

**Problem code:**

```
# insert the student object into MongoDB
object_id = student_collection.insert(a_student.to_JSON())
```

**Solution:**

```
object_id = student_collection.insert({"email": "daniel@mongocourse.com", "name": {"first": "Daniel", "last": "Watrous"}, "major": "Electrical Engineering"})
```

Even though we're saying "to_JSON()" here, the insert method gets confused and will throw an error when it goes to execute.  Because it's getting a string, it thinks it's a string, rather than JSON.

I'm using Python 3.5.  The version might have something to do with it too.  Maybe it worked with Python 2.7.

Hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue like you, and I found this solution:

```
import json    

valuestr = json.dumps(myclass, default=lambda x:x.__dict__)
value = json.loads(valuestr) # <-- returned data is not string
db.posts.insert(value)
```